# How to mark gradient effect on background as important?

Tags: html, css

```
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 20%, #000000 80%), url("../assets/img/bg.jpg");
```

I want to mark gradient effect on background image as *!important*. is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can't set a single argument of an attribute as `!important`, what is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a single argument of an attribute as `!important`.

But if you are looking for a way to add a constant overlay to your images, you can use pseudo-elements:

```css
.pic {
  /* change the image to whatever you want */
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/100/100);
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.pic::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* image overlay, will always be on top of whatever image */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20%, #000000 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="pic"></div>
```